# weird case of IE not applying <style> contents

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, dom

I write JavaScript code that is deployed on numerous sites.

Yes, we're an Ad Network. We're the Evil Forces of the Internet.

That said, we usually use the following approach to adding styles to the site:

```
var d = document.createElement('style');
d.type = 'text/css';
d.textContent = 'body {display: none!important; }';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(d);
```

Execute this via js console, and the page should clear.

Except when it doesnt. 
We just encountered such a case: 
Internet Explorer 9 does NOT apply the style on the following page:

http://www.brigitte.de/mode/trends/deutscher-fernsehpreis-2012-1142578/

The page is displayed in IE's "IE9 browser mode" as well as "IE9 document mode".
Executing the example script w/ activated profiler shows no other scripts being triggered on insertion of the  tag.

I need ideas. Anything. Is this a rare IE bug? Any workarounds I could try?

---

edit:

solved. We fell victim to IE's [31-stylesheets-bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262161/en-us?fr=1).

In short: Internet Explorer will only interpret up to 31 stylesheets. Any further styles are discarded. [I'm going to get drunk](http://cheezburger.com/4410491392). Have a nice weekend.

Comment: have you tried innerHTML instead of textContent?

Comment: now I have ;) . But it doesnt change a thing.

Comment: Worth a try! Also there it should be `display: none !important;`

Comment: Please don't put "solved" in the title to your question. Add your solution as an answer and then accept it, or flag your question for deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved. We fell victim to IE's [31-stylesheets-bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262161/en-us?fr=1).

In short: Internet Explorer will only interpret up to 31 stylesheets. Any further styles are discarded. [I'm going to get drunk](http://cheezburger.com/4410491392). Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you add style: http://jsfiddle.net/YqhDp/